# "died from" versus "died of"

Tags: prepositions, coordination

Why can't I say “She died **from** drinking 18 cans of Coca-Cola”?
Instead, the correct sentence would be “She died **of** drinking 18 cans of Coca-Cola”.

Why does that happen?

Comment: I have just read that die of refers to a direct cause and die from to an indirect cause of death.

Answer (score 2):

Die is a verb which is followed by certain appropriate prepositions.

> Die **of** diseases and old age and bad habits.
> Die **from** wounds and injuries.
> Die **in** an accident.
> Die **for** a great cause or for the country.

So in for your example sentence, "She died **of** drinking 18 cans of coco-cola." is correct.

The [Merriam-Webster definition of "die"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die) has more examples that might help you.

Comment: Actually, [Longman's dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/die) has a helpful note about prepositions with 'die': "GRAMMAR: Prepositions with die
• Someone dies of or from a disease or injury:
*He died of a heart attack.* / 
*He died from a heart attack.*  
Die of is more common than die from. ✗Don’t say: *He died because of a heart attack.*
• Someone dies in an accident:
*He died in a car crash.*
✗Don’t say: *He died by a car crash.*
• Someone dies for a person, place, or idea that they want to protect:
*These men died for our freedom.*"

Answer (score 0):

Both actually work. It just depends who you are talking to. Different people will find different versions more natural. Either way, everyone will understand the point you are trying to make.